# create a xml file on server and download to client asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, httpcontext

I try to create and xml type file in an asp.net page using c# and downloadto client, here is my code but it doesn't work.

```
public void SaveKml()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    //create xml/kml document here
    StringBuilder kmlpath = new StringBuilder();

    kmlpath.Append("nameG");
    kmlpath.Append("_");
    kmlpath.Append(parYE1);
    kmlpath.Append("_");
    kmlpath.Append(parID1);
    kmlpath.Append(".kml"); // google earth 

    string path1 = @"~/App_Data/" + kmlpath.ToString();

    doc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path1));
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path1);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content - disposition", "attachment; filename =" +fi.Name);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName,0,fi.Length);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your XML file is blank, you need to specify the root node here,
refer below link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, it's not blank. it filled up by some georefernce value. and is there any problem with my question?the problem is not with xml/klm file.